# JavaScript Iterating over object properties - Stuck in circular reference loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a big object (it has around 200 properties) and I want to print it like so:

```
[property1: alice, property2: bob, property3: 42, ...]
```

If the property is a function, I want it to print the code of the function and if it is an array, I want it to print every element of that array. Also, if the property is an object it should also print it's properties and so on...

I have tried to implement this recursively but of course the call stack got too big quite quickly. Then I moved on to a iterative implementation using a stack. Here is what I've got:

```
function getPropertyString(obj) {
    var res = "";
    var stack = [];
    stack.push(obj);
    while(stack.length > 0){
        var object = stack.pop();
        res += "[";
        for(var prop in object) {
            if(prop == null) continue;
            if(typeof object[prop] === 'object') {
                stack.push(object[prop]);
            } else {
                res += prop + ": " + 
                       object[prop].toString().replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, "") + ", ";
            }
        }
        res += "],";
    }
    return res;
}
```

This works fine if you have an object like

```
var a = {
    b : {
        c : "hello",
        d : "world"
    },
    e : "alice",
    f : "bob",
    g : function() {
        console.log("hello");
    },
    h : [1, 2, 3]
}
```

but let's say you modify `a` so that `a.x = {}; a.x.prototype = a;`. Then my function would get stuck in an infinite loop.

How could I get around this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the prototype chain (or `.prototype` properties), circular references can always happen. (simplest example: `var a = {}; a.x = a;`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Should I change the title then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of objects that has been processed from the 
stack, and do not process them again: (I marked the lines I added to do this)

```js
function getPropertyString(obj) {
    var res = "";
    var stack = [];
    var objectHistory = []; // added this
    stack.push(obj);
    while(stack.length > 0){
        var object = stack.pop();
        if (objectHistory.indexOf(object) != -1) continue;  // added this
        objectHistory.push(object);  // added this
        res += "[";
        for(var prop in object) {
            if(prop == null) continue;
            if(typeof object[prop] === 'object') {
                stack.push(object[prop]);
            } else {
                res += prop + ": " +
                       object[prop].toString().replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, "") + ", ";
            }
        }
        res += "],";
    }
    return res;
}

var a = {
    b : {
        c : "hello",
        d : "world"
    },
    e : "alice",
    f : "bob",
    g : function() {
        console.log("hello");
    },
    h : [1, 2, 3]
};

a.x = {
  i: "I am X"
};
a.x.prototype = a;

console.log(getPropertyString(a));
```

Comment: Simple. I like it!

Comment: Always satisfying to please with a simple solution :-) . If this answer is working for you, please remember to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

How about `JSON.stringify` it first and pass a function as the 2nd argument (so called 'replacer') in order to transform methods to strings too, because in default `JSON.stringify` discards functions. This way you will have all the properties and if you set an 'infinite loop' then JSON will alert you about it.

Comment: Well as I said, the method works for Object `a` (it also prints the method etc.). And I don't want an alert, but a function that takes care of that 'loop' case.